# Unattended install of Ubuntu 18.04 minimal desktop?

Tags: ubuntu-minimal, 18.04

I've read a lot about the "minimal desktop" flavor that will be included in Ubuntu 18.04.  What do I need to put it the preseed file to do an unattended install of it?

I assume it's some variation of the existing

```
tasksel tasksel/first multiselect ubuntu-desktop
```

(from https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/example-preseed.txt) but I don't know what the legal choices are.

Comment: Seems like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) as currently described. Few folks actually want a minimal system as the end product; most want to build up from that minimal base. In an unattended install, that building is also part of the install process. Consider describing the final result you actually want.

Answer (score 4):

The available options are documented in [the Ubuntu installation guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/amd64/apbs04.html), section B.4.10 which reads:

You can choose to install any combination of tasks that are available. Available tasks as of this writing include:

- standard (standard tools)
- ubuntu-desktop
- kubuntu-desktop
- edubuntu-desktop
- lubuntu-desktop
- ubuntu-gnome-desktop
- xubuntu-desktop
- ubuntu-mate-desktop
- lamp-server
- print-server (print server)

However, minimal install is not a d-i key, but an ubiquity one. Add this to the preseed:

```
ubiquity ubiquity/minimal_install boolean true
```

(Obtained by reading the [Ubiquity source code](https://git.launchpad.net/ubiquity)).

Comment: +1. A link to this source code would be welcome :)